# Are there utilities for converting static libraries to C header?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, clang

> Hi, I know that this question sounds quite strange, but suddenly there
> is such a utility, and I did not find it.

Are there programs or scripts that make a header from a static library?

For example, there is a function foo and I know it is in a static library compiled for a specific architecture, without calling system calls and other things that it could depend on, just code that calculates something and returns the result. If there was a script, it could extract the already compiled code and present it in the header file as a static variable (section), and add the foo function, when called, the static variable was converted to a function reference and called.

For what it is necessary, yes, the answer is a little strange, but it is easy to add an already compiled library as a simple header file without changing the program's linking.

Comment: No, and there essentially cannot be. For non-trivial functions, the object code in the library generally does not contain enough information to properly determine what the intended parameter types are.

Comment: Ask library author for the .h file.

Comment: Your question makes little sense as worded.  Did you want a header file declaring the _interface_ of the library or to actually to _decompile_ the library as source code in a header.  The latter is not possible and you would not want the code in a header in any case.  What you need is the original source code from which the library was created.  Compilation is a one-way process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the answer is no - there is no way to get a full picture of the C interface to the library from just the library. Now this being said - with debug symbols it may be possible to get some semblance of an interface, but that is not a robust solution as it does not extract non-trivial types.

Comment: Creating a header form a _known_ documented interface is trivial, but what the question seems to be asking is to _extract the code_ from the static library (essentially decompilation).  This answer does not address that.

Comment: @Clifford so far as I understood it they were asking how to extract the interface to a library from the library - "header from a library". But you are right if they did mean perfectly reconstructing the original interface as opposed to generating a new one

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point.  See my comment on the actual question.  It is unclear perhaps, but it seems not about _interfaces_ but the actual implementation in a header - which itself makes no sense.